# In tkinter, how can I save text entered into a text area into an already open text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code currently functions as follows:

create directory --> change working directory to created directory --> option to generate .txt files into directory, viewable in a listbox --> select a .txt file from listbox and view contents in a text widget.

What I am struggling with is then finding a way to enter text and save / append to the currently open/viewed text file in the text widget.

code:

```
from tkinter import *
from os import mkdir, getcwd, path, listdir, chdir

def dir_gen():
    curr_dir = getcwd()
    print("curr dir", curr_dir)
    fin_dir = path.join(curr_dir, r'note_folder')
    print("fin dir", fin_dir)
    if not path.exists(fin_dir):
        makedirs(fin_dir)
        print("directory created")

dir_gen()

flist = listdir("note_folder")
print("flist", flist)

chdir("note_folder")


def main_gui():
    window = Tk()
    window. geometry("400x400")
    window.config(bg="#000000")

    def go_home():
        window.destroy()
        main_gui()
        print("refreshed window")


    lbox = Listbox(window)
    lbox.place(x=20, y=20)

    listdir()
    print("listdir", listdir())
    for l in listdir():
        lbox.insert(END, l)


    add_note_entry = Entry(window)
    add_note_entry.place(x=20, y=190)
    add_note_entry.config(width=20)

    add_line_entry = Entry(window)
    add_line_entry.place(x=200, y=300)
    add_line_entry.config(width=27)


    def add_note():
        title = add_note_entry.get()
        hdl = open(title + ".txt", "w")
        hdl.close(), go_home()

    def open_note(event):
        x = lbox.curselection()[0]
        print("x", x)
        file = lbox.get(x)
        print("file", file)
        with open(file, 'r+') as file:
            file = file.read()
        text_output.delete('1.0', END)
        text_output.insert(END, file)

    def save_note():
        pass


    add_note_button = Button(window, command=add_note)
    add_note_button.place(x=40, y=210)
    add_note_button.config(width=10, height=2, text=("ADD NOTE"))

    save_note_button = Button(window, command=save_note)
    save_note_button.place(x=240, y=345)
    save_note_button.config(width=10, height=2, text=("SAVE NOTE"))

    text_output = Text(window)
    text_output.place(x=200, y=20)
    text_output.config(height=15, width=20)

    lbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", open_note)

    window.mainloop()

main_gui()
```

I have tried

```
  def save_note(event):
        line = add_line_entry.get()
        x = lbox.curselection()[0]
        file = lbox.get(x)
        file = str(filename)
        print("file2", file)
        with open(file, 'a') as file:
            file.write(line)
        open_note()
```

and

```
  def save_note():
        x = lbox.curselection()[0]
        file = lbox.get(x)
        hdl = open(file, 'r+')
        nt = text_output.get(1)
        for l in nt:
            hdl.write(l)
        hdl.close()
```

as the main ways to get this functioning, unable to adjust either to get them running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second function, tkinter does not expect the text widget get function to be indexed with an integer. Here I have recreated the second save function but edited the line `nt = text_output.get(1)` to `nt = text_output.get('1.0', 'end')`. This gets everything from the first to last character in a tkinter text widget.

```
    def save_note():
        x = lbox.curselection()[0]
        file = lbox.get(x)
        hdl = open(file, 'r+')
        nt = text_output.get('1.0', 'end')
        for l in nt:
            hdl.write(l)
        hdl.close()
```